# Как сделать в Chrom'е так чтобы результаты поиска выводились в домене google.com?

Tags: google-chrome, search

Как сделать в Chromе так, чтобы результаты поиска выводились не в `google.ru`, а в домене `google.com`
Когда я говорю в домене `google.com`, я имею ввиду браузер сам по умолчанию искал в домене `google.com` в **английской версии**. Просто я вот к чему все это говорю, когда при очистке браузера `ctrl+shift+delete`, как ни странно все равно он ищет в `google.ru`

Может какой-то файл поправить в самом Chrome? Есть варианты?

Просто для меня это нужная вещь. Допустим в англоязычном версии выдачи `google` всегда выдает актуальную и качественную информацию, `чем google.ru`

Answer (score 1):

Ответ можно найти, как обычно, на [официальном сайте](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/873?hl=ru).

> Если вы хотите использовать для поиска не локальный домен, а
>   google.com, у вас есть два варианта действий:
>
> - Если вы попали с google.com на другой домен (например, google.ru), нажмите на ссылку google.com в правом нижнем углу страницы.
> - Создайте закладку http://www.google.com/ncr. Когда вы открываете эту ссылку, выполняется переадресация на google.com. Примечание. После
>     удаления кеша или файлов cookie вам понадобится снова создать такую
>     закладку.